# Confusing class behavior in python

Tags: python, arrays, class, for-loop

I don't understand the behavior of arrays in classes when looping over over them in an array of objects.

Ok, let's say i have this code:

```
class example:
    arr = []
    def __init__(self):
        self.arr.append(69)

examples = []
for i in range(5):
    examples.append(example())
for e in examples:
    for a in e.arr:
        print(str(a))
```

Expected output is five 69s, but it prints 25 of them. Why?

EDIT: I've somehow figured out that all the instances use the SAME ARRAY, how is that possible if i used `self`?

Comment: You should name your classes with a capital letter, to distinguish them from variables. It’ll make the whole snippet much more clear.

Comment: You never *assigned anything* to `self.arr`, which would have made it an instance attribute.  Merely reading the attribute does not create anything, it instead looks up the inheritance chain and finds the attribute in the class - and will find the same attribute each time it's looked up.

Comment: Testing code fragments like this in `https://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit `can be helpful in showing you what is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`example` has a *list*-valued *class* attribute, so all instances of `example` share that same list. (You never assigned to `self.arr`, so you did not create an *instance* attribute that shadows the class attribute.) If you had created one instance of `example,` then `example.arr` would have one element. If you had created 50 instances of `example,` then `example.arr` would have 50 elements.

As a resut, `example.arr` contains 5 elements, *because* you created 5 instances of `example`. (There aren't 5 objects each with a singleton list specific to it.) Your nested loop prints the full contents of a 5-element list 5 times, resulting in 25 lines of output.

What you likely intended was for your class to be defined as follows:

```
class Example:
    def __init__(self):
        self.arr = []
        self.arr.append(69)
        # Which would be the long way of writing
        # self.arr = [69]
```

Now the code

```
examples = []
for i in range(5):
    examples.append(example())
```

would give you a list of objects whose `arr` attribute each contains a single element, and

```
for e in examples:
    for a in e.arr:
        print(str(a))
```

would iterate over the distinct *singleton* list of each object, producing the expected 5 lines of output.

Comment: So what you're saying is, in order to make the variables NOT static, you need to define them in the ```__init__``` method?

Comment: Yes. And don't call them "static", as the term has no real meaning in Python. The `arr` you defined in the `class` statement is a *class* attribute (an attribute belonging to a *class*, not any particular instance of the class). Assignments to `obj.arr` create/modify an *instance* attribute (an attribute associate with `obj` specifically, not any other instance of the same class).

Comment: (`__init__` doesn't really have anything to do with instance attributes, other than being a *common* place to initially define the attributes for an instance after it has been created. You can define instance attributes anywhere you have a reference to an object, not just in `__init__`.)

Comment: OK! I tested it and it works as intended! Your explanation is awesome and simple. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As you are updating the class variable each time, the arr variable in class appends the number, every time it is called. To avoid the behaviour, try the below if this was your intention.

```py
    class example:
            #arr = []
            def __init__(self):
                    self.arr = []
                    self.arr.append(69)  ## now that the self.arr is defined it acts as object variable, else it will try to find the variable in the class.
    
    examples = []
    for i in range(2):
            examples.append(example())
    
    for e in examples:
            for a in e.arr:
                    print(str(a))
```

Please find the below reference, hope this helps:
https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#class-and-instance-variables

Answer (score -1):

`example.arr` does only have 5 elements in it:

```py
print(example.arr)
```

… but you’re iterating over `example.arr` 5 times (once for every one of the 5 `example` objects in the `examples` list)

Comment: That is the problem, the array is meant to be for 1 instance, so it should have 1 element. Is this possible to do?

Comment: The main reason why this is happening is because they are appending the `example()` class to the list wherein the `arr` is already including `69` 5 times.

Comment: @AverageLinuxEnjoyer read up on class attributes, how they differ from instances attributes. You objects don’t have their own instance attribute called `arr`, so when you look up `self.arr`, what you’re getting back is the shared class-level attribute.

Comment: But how do i make the array exclusive for the instances (making it NOT static)?

Comment: By assigning a _new list_ to `self.arr` in the `__init__`. As I said, the terms to look up and read more on are "class attribute" and "instance attribute"

Answer (score -1):

You are appending `69` to `arr` 5 times while simultaneously appending the class to `examples` list. If you try this:

```
class example:
    arr = []
    def __init__(self):
        self.arr.append(69)
        print(self.arr)
```

You can see that your `arr` already has `69` 5 times.

Then, when you append the `example` class to your list it keeps on appending the class, however simultaneously the `example` class keeps on updating. Your current `examples` list outputs this:

```
[<__main__.example object at 0x000001A2026EFAF0>, <__main__.example object at 0x000001A2026EFAC0>, <__main__.example object at 0x000001A2026EFA90>, <__main__.example object at 0x000001A2026EF8B0>, <__main__.example object at 0x000001A2026EF730>]
```

This whole list contains of the example class which has been lately updated to the `arr` containg `69` 5 times.
To make your code functional with OOP try this:

```
class example:
    arr = []
    def __init__(self):
        self.arr.append(69)

examples = []
for i in range(5):
    example.arr = []
    examples.append(example())
for e in examples:
    for a in e.arr:
        print(a)
```

**Edit:** Thanks to @chepner for the clarification of OP's requirement.

Comment: Your rewrite does something quite different, and I think misses the point that the OP misunderstood, which is that each object does *not* have its own list attribute.

Comment: Oh okay, I get it. Updated :)